# Linux OpenSuse42.3 - port status - filtered

Tags: linux, port, opensuse

I have a problem, which I hope somebody can point me to the right direction.

**Problem >>>**
A) Our external provider (connects via VPN) needs to access "OpenSuse42.3" to specific ports, which 
   "nmap" or "ncat" tools shows as "filtered"  or "refused".
B) No services are listening on these ports.
C) No firewall is running on this server.
D) Security team opened these ports on firewall with evidence that connection get reset by server 
   "OpenSuse42.3".

**Test runs from "10.10.10.2"   to  "10.10.10.1" (problem server)**  from provider VPN connection (from my computer)

**Example 1 :  from "10.10.10.2"**

```
 >>> nmap -sT -p1101,3050 10.10.10.1
 >>>
 PORT     STATE    SERVICE
 1101/tcp filtered pt2-discover
 3050/tcp filtered gds_db
```

**Example 2 : from "10.10.10.2"**

```
  nc -z -v 10.10.10.1 1101
  Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
  Ncat: Connection refused.


  nc -z -v 10.10.10.1 3050
  Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
  Ncat: Connection refused.
```

**Example 3: on server "10.10.10.1"**

## tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 1101 or port 3050 -v

tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

13:00:28.940582 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 32383, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
   10.10.10.2.58000 > 10.10.10.1.1101: Flags [S], cksum 0xa3fc (correct), seq 3906215335, win 29200, 
   options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1388733400 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

13:00:28.940662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40440, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.10.10.1.1101 > 10.10.10.2.58000: Flags [R.], cksum 0x347b (correct), seq 0, ack 3906215336, 
    win 0, length 0

13:00:31.263502 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 60627, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    10.10.10.2.40830 > 10.10.10.1.3050: Flags [S], cksum 0x8bc2 (correct), seq 3504308280, win 29200, 
    options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1388735723 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

13:00:31.263569 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 40888, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    10.10.10.1.3050 > 10.10.10.2.40830: Flags [R.], cksum 0x2554 (correct), seq 0, ack 3504308281, 
    win 0, length 0

**BUT**

As soon as I put something on the server like - "nc -l 1101"   or "nc -l 3050"
problem disappears, which probably makes sense. To my knowledge "nmap" tool usually shows port status as "closed" if port is not firewalled and service is not running and "open" if service is running on this port.

**Question**

Are ports opened or closed ??? What else do I check, because provider keep insisting that ports are closed on "10.10.10.1" and he cannot continue his work.

Please let me knoe if something is unclear in this situation and I will respond.

Appreciate it !!!!

Comment: This question does not belong on SO, SO is for programming question only.  That being said, you say **B) No services are listening on these ports.**.  So you can open all the firewalls you want, if nothing processes the connections to the ports, why are you expecting it to work?  It's like you are dialing someone's phone and no one is home to answer.  Go on server 10.10.10.1 and run `netstat -an|grep LISTEN` to see if the ports are open in LISTEN.  You can then use `lsof` to see which process handles theses ports.

Comment: The fact that if you add `nc -l` on 10.10.10.1 and it works shows that the ports are open, when something listens on them.  So your ports are open up to the server, but the server needs to do something with the connections.

Comment: Yep. nothing listening on these ports, I have already checked.  Makes sense.